# Cypress test material ui autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui, cypress

How can I get a value from the dropdown in cypress for the material ui autocomplete.

Currently it gets to the selection of the autocomplete but I cant seem to get to the dropdown or type anything. There will always be a test user called "ntest_user" so I thought maybe I can autocomplete it instead of clicking dropdown but no dice

```
  <Autocomplete
    id="combo-box"
    data-testid="tagAutocomplete"
    options={userz}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
    value={userId}
    onChange={viewUserz}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params}
      label="User Id"
      variant="outlined" />}
  />
</FormControl>


cy.get('.tagAutocomplete li[data-option-index="0"]').click();
```

Comment: Does your dropdown has any value when you click it? Can you add a screenshot for that ?

Comment: Yes inside the dropdown there is "ntest_user"

Comment: could you please give me feedback about the following?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815424/how-to-wirte-a-test-to-select-movie-from-muiautocomplete-root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get("#combo-box").click();
cy.get("li[data-option-index="0"]").contains("ntest_user").then((option) => {
   option[0].click();
})
```

OP was able to solve by this:

```js
cy.get("#combo-box").click();
cy.contains("ntest_user").then((option) => {
   option[0].click();
})
```

Comment: Very close but getting error expected to find selector but never found it

Comment: selector is just a dummy text, you have to use the actual selector there. This looks like the locator of the first dropwdown element `li[data-option-index="0"]` but I am not sure.

Comment: I removed the .get("selector") and just left it as cy.contains etc and that works ! Is there any issues doing it that way ?

Comment: Nopes that works as well `cy.contains()` is a valid command.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, how did you know that the above commands would fix it ? Is there some docs you could point me to ?

Comment: I faced the same issue once and using the jquery click instead of the cypress click helped me, I read that somewhere but don't exactly remember where.