# How to wirte a test to select Movie from MuiAutocomplete-root

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, cypress

I am using Materil ui with React with Typescript and I want to write a test for the autocomplete with Cypress.
I did the following:

- identify Autocomplete component & open it,
- choose an option,
- verify the value in the input

**Quellcode**:

```
<div class="MuiAutocomplete-root MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon css-4ec9ly-MuiAutocomplete-root" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" xpath="1">
   <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth MuiTextField-root css-wb57ya-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root">
      <label class="MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-sizeSmall MuiInputLabel-standard MuiFormLabel-root MuiFormLabel-colorPrimary css-577pmh-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root" data-shrink="false" for="movies-filter" id="movies-filter-label" style="">Movies
      </label>
   <div class="MuiInput-root MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-sizeSmall MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot css-4op3e8-MuiInputBase-root-MuiInput-root">
      <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="movies-filter" placeholder="Start typing" type="text" class="MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused css-nz481w-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="" style="">
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**movie.cy.ts**

- first try:

```
cy.contains('.MuiAutocomplete-root', 'Movies').click(); // identify Autocomplete component & open it
    cy.contains('A1-Test1').click(); // choose an option
    cy.contains('.MuiAutocomplete-root', 'Movies')  
      .find('input')                               
      .should('have.value', 'Movie1'); // verify the value in the input
```

[image]

- second try:

```
cy.get('#Movies-filter').click().focused().type('Mo');
cy.contains('Movie1').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me like the follwing:

```
cy.wait(2000) // waiting for ajax to complete (till the request is resolved)
cy.get('#The MUI ID').click({force:true}).focused().type('Germany');
cy.contains('Germany').click({force:true});
```